# Sql Server - Order by issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables. First is the account table, then there is the contact table, and the phone table.

Requirement of the query im trying to write here is that for a given account, show the main contact at top with all of its phone numbers, then show the rest of contacts sorted by name. The phones also must appear in a pre-defined sequence. Home phone number first, then work phone number etc etc.

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT c.ContactID, c.FullName, p.PhoneCategory, p.Phone, a1.MainContactID 
FROM Contact c
JOIN Phone p ON p.ContactID = c.ContactID
JOIN Account a1 ON a1.AccountID= c.AccountID
WHERE a1.AccountID= 1000
ORDER BY 
c.FullName, 
CASE PhoneCategory
    WHEN 'Home Phone' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Business Phone' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Cell Phone' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Fax' THEN 4
    WHEN 'Other Phone' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Email Address' THEN 6
    WHEN 'E-Mail' THEN 6
END
```

By running this I get the the list sorted by name, and the numbers also appear in the correct order. The only issue is that I cant determine how to get the maincontact to show up at the top

Edit: Had typed c1.MainContactID instead of a1

Comment: You say c1 maincontactid but c1 is not defined in the query.

Comment: edited. Should say a1.maincontactid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help if you showed some more of the database schema. I.e.: how can you determine that some contact is a main contact?

I have two ideas:

1. You could use two separate queries and use a UNION command to create one result set.
2. From what I see here, I suppose that for a main contact, its ID corresponds with the `MainContactID` of an account? In that case I figure you could do it with one query by using an Left Outer Join on the `MainContactID` column and then sorting on that? This column will be NULL for other contacts, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what `c1` is -- but if it is a join not shown that gives you an id for main contact and null for non-main contact then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT c.ContactID, c.FullName, p.PhoneCategory, p.Phone, c1.MainContactID 
FROM Contact c
JOIN Phone p ON p.ContactID = c.ContactID
JOIN Account a1 ON a1.AccountID= c.AccountID
WHERE a1.AccountID= 1000
ORDER BY 
CASE
  WHEN a1.MainContactID = c.ContactID THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END,
c.FullName, 
CASE PhoneCategory
    WHEN 'Home Phone' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Business Phone' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Cell Phone' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Fax' THEN 4
    WHEN 'Other Phone' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Email Address' THEN 6
    WHEN 'E-Mail' THEN 6
END
```

Comment: My bad. It should have been a1.MainContactID. Made a typo while typing out the question. This would work as well, although I prefer Martao's answer. +1 just because despite an error on my part, you still came up with a solution.

Comment: @Mogambo - ok I changed it to work now that I understand where maincontactid is stored.